# Some questions on the definition of $n$-simplex.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hatcher P102 last paragraph:

> $n$-simplex is the smallest convex set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ containing $n+1$ points $v_0, \dots, v_n$ that do not lie in a hyperplane of dimension less than $n$.

I found this statement very confusing. By $\mathbb{R}^m$, does it just mean a space greater or equal to $n$? And also, by "do not lie in a hyperplane of dimension less than $n$", does it mean these $n$ points form $n$ linearly independent vectors, which lies in exactly a hyperplane of dimension $n$?

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf

Comment: Note that those $n+1$ linear independent vectors can still be in a $n$D-plane that does not pass through the origin of $\mathbb R$.  However, the set $\{v_i-v_0|i=1,\ldots,n\}$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: It's an $n$-dimensional triangle in $m$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 3):

For your question, $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is the ambient space. An $n$ -simplex is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ linearly homeomorphic to the set

$$\{x_{0}+x_{1}\cdots+x_{n}\}= 1,x_{i}\ge 0,0\le i\le n$$

You should think about what this is like in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and how it might like in $\mathbb{R}^{m},m\ge n$ in general. Draw some pictures might help. Beaware that there are $n+1$ points, **not** $n$ points, for a $n$-simplex. They are **not** in a hyperlane of dimension less than $n$.

Comment: Your displayed formula is not a set but an equation, which uses $\cong$ instead of $=$ for some reason. Also you need to insist that each $x_i$ is nonnegative.

Comment: $\{(x_0,\ldots,x_n)\,|\, x_0+\cdots +x_n=1, x_i\geq 0\}$

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at $\Bbb{R}^3$.  If you had $4$ points lying on a $2$-dimensional plane lying in $\Bbb{R}^3$, then the volume of the tetrahedron connecting the points has zero volume.  If one of the points lies off any plane though, the tetrahedron has some volume to it.

$\Bbb{R}^m$ is just the set of $m$-tuples of real numbers turned into a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ by the natural operations.

Comment: Oh that is very helpful! So $m$ is just some bigger space equal or great than $n$ so that it can contain those $n+1$ points, right?

Comment: Yeah, I think there might be misprint in your book or something.